# How to send 2 values from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to send 2 values to the controller, one of the values is fixed and the other is a dynamic value that is fetched from a ViewModel.

The dynamic value is displayed in a table, and it is an input, of type submit, which if I click on it, both the fixed and dynamic value try to send them to a controller method, but they do not seem to be arriving. I wanted to know if you could help me send them and that they arrive.

This is my view:

```
<tbody>
         <form action="~/Home/ReadOption" method="post">
               <label hidden value="delivery" name="selection"></label>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                                 <tr>
                                     <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="@item.DeliveryNumber" name="identi">@item.DeliveryNumber</button></td>
                                     <td>@item.OrderNumber</td>
                                     <td>@item.RemitNumber</td>
                                     <td>@item.CantPhotos</td>
                                     <td>@item.Date</td>
                                     <td>@item.Time</td>
                                 </tr>
                   }
         </form>
      </tbody>
```

And this is my controller method:

```
[Httppost]
public IActionResult ReadOption(string selection, string identi)
        {
            List<OrderViewModel> OrderList;

            try
            {
                identi = CleanString(identi);

                if (identi == null || identi == "")
                {
                    returnView("Index");
                }

                switch (selection)
                {
                    case "order":
                        OrderList = ViewOrder(identi);
                        return View("Order", orderList);
                    case "remit":
                        OrderList = ViewRemittance(identi);
                        return View("Order", orderList);
                    case "delivery":
                        OrderList = ViewDelivery(identi);
                        return View("Order", orderList);
                }

                returnView();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.error = ex.Message;
                return View("Error");
            }
```

From the view I want to send the value of the label (name="selection", value="delivery") and the input (name="identi", value="@item.NumeroDelivery").

I tried with the form, with the `@using(Html.Beginform)`... with an `onclick=@Url.Action("ReadOption", "Home", new{selection = "delivery", identi = @item.DeliveryNumber})` in the `input/button`

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
 <input hidden value="delivery" name="selection"></input>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: So.. this really worked for me, it was only change label for input...I'm stupid, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

the label is not a field so you can't send it via the form, you need to use a hidden field instead of the label

something like that

in your view

```
@Html.Hidden("selection", "delivery")
```

and also, the submit button can't pass the value, you need to use another hidden field, the button only trigger the submit action

```
@Html.Hidden("identi", @item.DeliveryNumber)
```

Comment: I will try it, thank you very much!, but how can I send it? The input I need to send (@item.DeliveryNumber) is dynamic, how can I send the identical DeliveryNumber that I clic on of my table?